# How do I generate sequential attribute values using LINQ-to-XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have some xml files in the format as shown below or maybe slightly different

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlpartsstyle.css"?>
<PARTS>
    <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
    <ASST>
        <PART no="xs@@">
            <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
            <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
            <MODEL ver="v-@@@@">P3B-F</MODEL>
            <COST>123.00</COST>
        </PART>
        <PART no="xs@@">
            <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
            <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
            <MODEL ver="v-@@@@">All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
            <COST>160.00</COST>
        </PART>
        <PART no="xs@@">
            <ITEM>Sound Card</ITEM>
            <MANUFACTURER>Creative Labs</MANUFACTURER>
            <MODEL ver="v-@@@@">Sound Blaster Live</MODEL>
            <COST>80.00</COST>
        </PART>
    </ASST>
</PARTS>
```

I'm trying to generate the attribute values of node `<PART>` namely **no** and `<MODEL>` namely **ver** in a sequential manner starting from value 1 and then incremented by +1 from the next `<PART>` node.
So, basically the desired output should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlpartsstyle.css"?>
<PARTS>
    <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
    <ASST>
        <PART no="xs1">
            <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
            <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
            <MODEL ver="v-1">P3B-F</MODEL>
            <COST>123.00</COST>
        </PART>
        <PART no="xs2">
            <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
            <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
            <MODEL ver="v-2">All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
            <COST>160.00</COST>
        </PART>
        <PART no="xs3">
            <ITEM>Sound Card</ITEM>
            <MANUFACTURER>Creative Labs</MANUFACTURER>
            <MODEL ver="v-3">Sound Blaster Live</MODEL>
            <COST>80.00</COST>
        </PART>
    </ASST>
</PARTS>
```

So what is the easiest way of doing this using LINQ-to-XML?

I was trying like

```
string filecontent=File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\12-apr.xml");
XDocument xml=XDocument.Parse(filecontent);
var parts=xml.Descendants("PART");
var models=xml.Descendants("PART").Elements("MODEL");
foreach (var part in parts)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count(); i++)
    {
        part.Attribute("no").Value="xs"+i.ToString();
    }

}
foreach (var model in models)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count(); i++)
    {
        model.Attribute("ver").Value="v-"+i.ToString();
    }

}
xml.Save(@"C:\Users\Desktop\12-apr.xml");
Console.ReadLine();
```

But its not working the way I intended to..
The output my code produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE PARTS SYSTEM "parts.dtd"[]>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="xmlpartsstyle.css"?>
<PARTS>
  <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
  <ASST>
    <PART no="xs2">
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL ver="v-2">P3B-F</MODEL>
      <COST>123.00</COST>
    </PART>
    <PART no="xs2">
      <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL ver="v-2">All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
      <COST>160.00</COST>
    </PART>
    <PART no="xs2">
      <ITEM>Sound Card</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>Creative Labs</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL ver="v-2">Sound Blaster Live</MODEL>
      <COST>80.00</COST>
    </PART>
  </ASST>
</PARTS>
```

Help

Comment: "But its not working the way I intended to" - so what *does* it do? It's unclear why you have nested loops... I suspect that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I updated with my question with my output..

Comment: Right, that's a much better question - and yes, the problem is that you're setting the attribute multiple times for each element. See my answer for how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested loops for no obvious reason... you're setting the attribute multiple times for *each* element, rather than setting the attribute once per element.

Once you've got rid of the nested loops, it's straightforward. It's simpler if you materialize your queries to lists though. Here's a complete example that produces the output you want:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var xml = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
        var parts = xml.Descendants("PART").ToList();
        var models = xml.Descendants("PART").Elements("MODEL").ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count; i++)
        {
            parts[i].Attribute("no").Value = $"xs{i+1}";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < models.Count; i++)
        {
            models[i].Attribute("ver").Value = $"v-{i+1}";
        }

        xml.Save("output.xml");
    }
}
```